# How do I detect a reference to an empty cell using Excel-DNA?

Tags: excel-dna

```
     //when the following line encounters a reference to
     //an empty cell, the method returns #VALUE
```

''''
         double val = dataRange[0];
         return val;
''''

```
[ExcelFunction(IsMacroType = true)]
public static object getVal([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)] double[] dataRange)
```

Comment: How exactly are you declaring your function in C#?

Comment: [ExcelFunction(IsMacroType = true)]
        public static object getVal([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)] double[] dataRange)

Answer (score 1):

By declaring the arguments of the function as `double` (or `double[]`) you're only allowed to have valid `double` values.

If you need to check for special values such as `ExcelEmpty` you need to declare the arguments of your function as `object` (or `object[]`).

e.g.

```
[ExcelFunction(IsMacroType = true)]
public static object getVal([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)] object[] dataRange)
{
    if (dataRange[0] == ExcelEmpty.Value)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

If you prefer to get the values via an `ExcelReference` then declare your input argument as `object` and check if it's an `ExcelReference`.

e.g.

```
[ExcelFunction(IsMacroType = true)]
public static object getVal([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)] object input)
{
    if (input is ExcelReference reference)
    {
        // ...

        var value = reference.GetValue();

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Caio Proiete -- That detects when the CELL is empty, but not when it contains a reference to an empty cell.

Comment: @SylviaGraham Same principle... Declare your argument as `object` safe-cast it to an `ExcelReference` the access the value via the reference, check for `ExcelEmpty`, etc...